# Dynamically change ng-if in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, pug

There is the following code (Jade):

```
    img(
      data-ng-src = "{{ ctrl.getAttachmentPreview(attachment) }}",
      data-ng-if  = "attachment.media_type == 'image'",
      data-image-error = "xxx"
    )
```

And my custom directive (Coffee):

```
module.exports = (app) ->
  app.directive 'imageError', ->
    restrict: 'A',
    link: ($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) ->
      el.attr('data-ng-if', 'false')
```

It's a prototype. I want to hide element in my custom directive using 'ng-if', but this code doesn't work (element has 'data-ng-if' with 'false' value, but still visible). How can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Setting attribute is not enough, you need to compile HTML too.

Comment: Give me code sample please

Comment: @dfsq Please, make answer please

Comment: I don't know CS or Jade, so I can only suggest: maybe you don't need to change attribute, maybe `el.hide()` is enough for your case?

Comment: May be it's a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

ng-if tells Angular to watch the `$scope` and evaluate the given expression if the `$scope` changes it, including DOM nodes depending on the result.

Direct manipulation it won't do anything.

Instead, manipulate the $scope:

```
module.exports = (app) ->
  app.directive 'imageError', ->
    restrict: 'A',
    link: ($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) ->
      $scope.attachment = media_type: 'image'
```